# Anyone with a C#, Delphi or FreePascal implementation of the PRESENT Ultra-Lightweight Block Cipher encryption?

Tags: c#, delphi, iso, freepascal, block-cipher

A short while ago a paper got published on [PRESENT: An Ultra-Lightweight Block Cipher](http://homes.esat.kuleuven.be/~abogdano/papers/present_ches07.pdf) by [Andrey Bogdanov](http://homes.esat.kuleuven.be/~abogdano/) et al becoming [ISO standard 29192-2:2012](http://www.iso.org/iso/iso_catalogue/catalogue_tc/catalogue_detail.htm?csnumber=56552).

Is there anyone that has a C#, Delphi or FreePascal implementation with unit tests?

This was asked [here](http://wiert.me/2012/03/06/anyone-with-a-c-delphi-or-freepascal-implementation-of-the-present-ultra-lightweight-block-cipher-encryption/) and I'm just trying to help.

Comment: What made you think this is appropriate for SO? You have been a registered user for long enough to know this is not constructive.

Comment: @Oded: please offline explain why "This question is not a good fit to our Q&A format. We expect answers to generally involve facts, references, or specific expertise; this question will likely solicit opinion, debate, arguments, polling, or extended discussion." as I think it involves facts, references and a request for specific expertise. You can reach me at firstname at lastname dot com. I didn't ask it here because I wanted to keep the Q/A in a smaller cicle before widening it, but my widening would have been SO.

Comment: @JeroenWiertPluimers - This is a request for code. I fully appreciate that the OP wants to help, but the only answers possible are "here you go there is the code you are asking". As such, it is not constructive.

Comment: I can imagine other answers like "here is a project trying to accomplish this in such and such language, please join it", or "here is an implementation in a different language, can you try this as a starter".

Comment: @Oded. I strongly disagree. This is fairly new and a lot of people are not even aware that it exists. Any reference provided could help. It's not like a homework question or gimme teh codz one. As for the "likely solicit opinion, debate, arguments, polling, or extended discussion", I don't see any of this in that question.

Comment: looks more like linkspam for me

Comment: @user539484 it is not meant as linkspam. But I can understand you see it as such. If so: my apologies.

Comment: Voted to reopen. I find it troubling that asking for an Implementatio of Algorithm X in Language Y might be considered off topic as per the FAQ.  This is a real question.

Comment: Humm, very strange that this had to be debated. A question about a bleeding edge technology and it get's closed? Linkspam is more likely to give you infections, not more knowledge. Thanks for the re-open guys!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

People at the [Shanghai Jiao Tong University](http://cis.sjtu.edu.cn) implemented an [8-bit version of this algorithm in C](http://cis.sjtu.edu.cn/index.php/Software_Implementation_of_Block_Cipher_PRESENT_for_8-Bit_Platforms).

Thanks [jecevans](http://en.gravatar.com/jecevans) for [commenting this answer on my blog](http://wiert.me/2012/03/06/anyone-with-a-c-delphi-or-freepascal-implementation-of-the-present-ultra-lightweight-block-cipher-encryption/#comment-6753).

**Edit 2**: more reference implementations

The [PRESENT (cipher) wikipedia page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PRESENT_%28cipher%29) recently added a link to [reference implementations in C and Python](http://www.lightweightcrypto.org/implementations.php) that include test vectors usable for unit testing.

**Edit 3** some literature on PRESENT

- http://mathsci.ucd.ie/~gmg/ECC2007Talks/poschmann_LWC.pdf
- http://rfidsec07.etsit.uma.es/slides/present/slides-4.4.PDF
- http://www.ist-ubisecsens.org/publications/present_ches2007.pdf

**Edit 1** (as per request by [RBA](https://stackoverflow.com/users/368364/rba)) the [entire response from Jecevans](http://wiert.me/2012/03/06/anyone-with-a-c-delphi-or-freepascal-implementation-of-the-present-ultra-lightweight-block-cipher-encryption/#comment-6753):

> [Jecevans](http://gravatar.com/jecevans) said
>
> [2012/03/06 at 16:53](http://wiert.me/2012/03/06/anyone-with-a-c-delphi-or-freepascal-implementation-of-the-present-ultra-lightweight-block-cipher-encryption/#comment-6753) [e](http://wiert.wordpress.com/wp-admin/comment.php?action=editcomment&c=6753) There is a C implementation here that should not
>   be to difficult to port. It leaves out the possibility of a 128 bit
>   key though.
>
> http://cis.sjtu.edu.cn/index.php/Software_Implementation_of_Block_Cipher_PRESENT_for_8-Bit_Platforms

Comment: @RBA will quote the response shortly.